# Buscar objeto por atributo da Classe PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes

Boa tarde, Gostaria de saber se tenho como buscar um objeto usando um atributo

Exemplo:

```
class Pessoa:



    def __init__(self, nome, idade, cpf)

        self.__nome = nome

        self.__idade = idade

        self.__cpf = cpf



pessoa1 = Pessoa('Thiago', 19, 000.000.000-00)

pessoa2 = Pessoa('Lucas', 18, 000.000.000-01)
```

Ai eu quero fazer acesso a pessoa1 só que passando o cpf.

Exemplo:

cpf 000.000.000-00

retorno

pessoa1

Ou algo parecido

Comment: Como planeja ser a busca por esse objeto? Será pelo terminal mesmo?

Comment: Sim, no caso terei alguns objetos criados, no próprio código fonte e de acordo com o que eu digitar no terminal, seja escolhido automaticamente qual o objeto que sofrerá as mudanças que um possível método fará

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa busca é com certeza factível, mas não existe uma implementação "pronta" em Python para fazê-la. Python não tem como saber *a priori* da existência da classe `Pessoa`, nem de que cada instância possui um atribuo `__cpf`.

Em outras palavras, você precisa escrever a lógica da busca por sua conta.

Como um exemplo, você poderia colocar todas as pessoas em um container, como uma lista:

```
pessoas = [pessoa1, pessoa2]
```

Então, você pode iterar sobre essa lista e encontrar uma pessoa específica comparando o atributo `__cpf` de cada pessoa com o CPF que você está buscando (note que o CPF é um string, um valor numérico não funcionará com pontos e travessões):

```
for p in pessoas:
    if p.__cpf == '000.000.000-00':
        print('Pessoa encontrada:', p)
```

Generalizando como uma função:

```
def busca_cpf(lista_pessoas, cpf_busca):
    for pessoa in lista_pessoas:
        if pessoa.__cpf == cpf_busca:
            return pessoa
```